# Show latest test run only in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, report

My report currently is displaying every test that is run. I would like to change the report format so that only the latest run of each test case is shown. For example, a test case is run twice, and I only want the latest run on the report. It should also work when new test cases are run in the future. What can use in XSLT that will do the change? What would the code look like or what kind of function will I use in XSLT? Let me know if you need more info on this. Thanks a ton.

My XML code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
    <Report>
    <Title>Test Run Summary - Last Run Only Report</Title> 
    <ProjectData>
    <Project>
    <ProjectId>71</ProjectId> 
    <ProjectGroupId>13</ProjectGroupId> 
    <Name>Master Project - Marketing</Name> 
    <Description xml:space="preserve"></Description> 
    <CreationDate>2012-06-20T21:40:58.187-05:00</CreationDate> 
    <ActiveYn>Y</ActiveYn> 
    <WorkingHours>8</WorkingHours> 
    <WorkingDays>5</WorkingDays> 
    <NonWorkingHours>0</NonWorkingHours> 
    <TimeTrackIncidentsYn>Y</TimeTrackIncidentsYn> 
    <TimeTrackTasksYn>Y</TimeTrackTasksYn> 
    <EffortIncidentsYn>Y</EffortIncidentsYn> 
    <EffortTasksYn>Y</EffortTasksYn> 
    <TasksAutoCreateYn>Y</TasksAutoCreateYn> 
    <ProjectGroupName>Siebel Projects Group</ProjectGroupName> 
    </Project>
    </ProjectData>
  <TestRunData>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8377</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS09 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-All Campaigns View</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3736</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T11:50:30.77-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T11:50:56.687-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8390</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS11 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-All Campaigns Across Organizations View</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3738</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T11:53:49.52-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T11:54:22.043-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8405</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS08 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-My Campaigns view</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3735</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <TestSetId>382</TestSetId> 
  <TestSetTestCaseId>3342</TestSetTestCaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T12:44:31.53-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T12:44:49.297-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <TestSetName>Campaign Promotion</TestSetName> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8406</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS09 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-All Campaigns View</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3736</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <TestSetId>382</TestSetId> 
  <TestSetTestCaseId>3343</TestSetTestCaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T12:45:31.293-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T12:45:59.473-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <TestSetName>Campaign Promotion</TestSetName> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8408</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS10 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-My Group's Campaigns View</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3737</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <TestSetId>382</TestSetId> 
  <TestSetTestCaseId>3344</TestSetTestCaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T12:46:30.26-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T12:46:59.343-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <TestSetName>Campaign Promotion</TestSetName> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  <TestRun>
  <TestRunId>8409</TestRunId> 
  <Name>TS11 Verify system should allow for bottom/detail level campaigns to be tied 1:1 to offers-All Campaigns Across Organizations View</Name> 
  <Description>Pre-requisites1. The Catalog Manager user should have been setup and is active in Siebel 2. Campaigns should be available3. Divisions should be available in Division pick applet4. Offer should be available</Description> 
  <TestCaseId>3738</TestCaseId> 
  <TestRunTypeId>1</TestRunTypeId> 
  <TesterId>156</TesterId> 
  <ExecutionStatusId>2</ExecutionStatusId> 
  <ReleaseId>223</ReleaseId> 
  <TestSetId>382</TestSetId> 
  <TestSetTestCaseId>3345</TestSetTestCaseId> 
  <ActualDuration>0</ActualDuration> 
  <StartDate>2013-07-22T12:47:57.73-05:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2013-07-22T12:48:47.617-05:00</EndDate> 
  <AttachmentsYn>N</AttachmentsYn> 
  <TestRunTypeName>Manual</TestRunTypeName> 
  <TesterName>Jagdish Thakur</TesterName> 
  <ExecutionStatusName>Passed</ExecutionStatusName> 
  <ReleaseName>Master Release - Siebel Marketing</ReleaseName> 
  <ReleaseVersionNumber>1.0.0.0</ReleaseVersionNumber> 
  <TestSetName>Campaign Promotion</TestSetName> 
  <PROJECT_ID>71</PROJECT_ID> 
  <CustomProperties /> 
  </TestRun>
  </TestRunData>
  </Report>
```

Comment: Hi, you'll need to provide the source XML for this. Also, what is acceptable for determining which is the latest run? Is position of a record in the XML resource enough, or is it start date?

Comment: I will post the XML code soon. I think the start date should determine the latest run! Thanks.

Comment: XML code is posted. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Do you need to stick to XSLT 1.0?